# Vue Js: how to view objects fron JSON API

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, object

in my Vue Js project i have data from API, and in JSON there is object stored and i can't view them in my code.. i tried to use  `this.obj =JSON.stringify(this.Flats);` and when i console.log it i can see all my data but i couldn't loop over them to view `payment` object

[image]

```js
BuildingsService.getAllFlats().then((response) => {
            this.Flats = response.data.response;

       
             this.obj =JSON.stringify(this.Flats);
             console.log(this.Flats,"dataaa")

           
        });
```

```html
  <div v-for="(object,index) in obj" :key="index"> //didn't work 
                               <span> {{object.flat_number}}   </span>

                                      <span > {{object.payment}}   </span>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're capturing the array in `Flats` but you're using `JSON.stringify` and storing the resulting string in `obj`...then logging the Array but expecting to iterate through the string?

Try this

```js
BuildingsService.getAllFlats().then((response) => {
    this.Flats = response.data.response;
    this.obj = this.Flats // transforming to a string and duplicating the variable seems kinda pointless btw
});
```

Or just loop through the Array you're already storing

```
<div v-for="(object,index) in Flats" :key="index"> // should work
```

Comment: this gives me `{ "cash_payment": { "paid_amount": "100000", "date": "2021-12-23" } }` after showing {{object.payment}} and what i want is to show data inside object paayment for ex i want to show `paid_amount`

Comment: Then you need to access the property with it's named path, i.e `{{ object.payment.cash_payment.paid_amount }}`

Comment: not working :/ it gives can' read property of payment

Comment: I can only assume that you have objects within your Flats array that do not contain the property you're looking for, in which case you'll need to use an `if` block around each nested property that you're trying to access. Something like `v-if="object.payment.cash_payment"` seeing as you're using Vue :)

Comment: property exists... but the API structure contains data like this `
            Status: "",
            price: "",
            city: "",
            paymentCash: {
                cash_payment: {
                    paid_amount: "",
                    date: "",
                },
            },`  which shows the `paymentcash` is an object and my problem is i can't show data inside this object but i can easily show status, price and city as well

Comment: Without a working example I can only assume that you're not accessing nested objects correctly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: yes .. i couldn't access those nested objects

Comment: The data is there for us all to see, now you just need to find it with the correct names :)

Comment: sry but this is not working,, it's not about correct names, in the image i provided above names are clear from console

Answer (score 0):

Cannot add through comments but probably

> can' read property of payment

error because of array has some objects that does not include payment object.
I believe implementing `v-if="object.payment"` will solve your problem.

Comment: this shows me data for the nested object inside JSON array `{
  "cash_payment": {
    "paid_amount": "100000",
    "date": "2021-12-23"
  }
}  
 {
  "cash_payment": {
    "paid_amount": "500,000",
    "date": "2021-12-22"
  }
}  `

Comment: while i want to access `paid_amount`, full JSon structure is:                                                                `{
  "status": "sold",
  "price": "100000",
  "currency": "USD",
  "_id": "61c21fa6f650480b7630badf",
  "flat_number": 1,
  "description": "This is a newly created flat.",
  "city": "duh",
  "payment": {
    "cash_payment": {
      "paid_amount": "100000",
      "date": "2021-12-23"
    }
  },`

Comment: Try to replace `<span> {{object.payment}}   </span>` with `<div v-if="object.payment"> <span> {{ object.payment.cash_payment.paid_amount }} </span> </div>` this

Comment: can't read property of cash_payment :/

Comment: If you can read payment value with condition, you have object that not include payment. Also you have some payment objects not include cash_payment. Also create condition for it.

Comment: didn't work :/ ... payment is object inside Json array of data thats why i can't access it